# TikZ: How can I extend a line to match another line (bad title, best I could do)

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap = round, line join = round, >=triangle 45,
    fixed point arithmetic]
    \coordinate (P1) at (-2, 0);
    \coordinate (P2) at (2.5, 0);
    \coordinate (P3) at (2, 0);

    \draw (P1) -- (P2);
    \draw[red] (P3) circle (.1cm);
    \path[name path = line] (P1) -- (70: 4.5cm and 2.5cm);
    \path[name path = arc] (P3) arc (0:70: 4cm and 2cm) coordinate (P4);
    \path[name intersections = {of = line and arc, by = P4}];

    \begin{scope}
      \clip (P4) rectangle (P3);
      \draw (P3) arc (0:70: 4cm and 2cm);
    \end{scope}

    \draw[-latex] (P1) -- (P4) node[above, scale = .75, pos = .5, fill = white,
    inner sep = 0cm] {\(\mathbf{r}\)};

    \draw[orange] let
      \p1 = (P1),
      \p3 = (P3),
      \p4 = (P4),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x3 - \x1, \y3 - \y1)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x4 - \x1, \y4 - \y1)},
      \n3 = {.75cm}
    in (P1) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node [scale = .75, shift = {(.5cm, -.25cm)}] {\(\nu\)};

    \path[name path = aux] (P4) circle [radius = 1bp];

    \draw[name intersections = {of = arc and aux}, -latex] (P4) --
    ($(intersection-2)!1cm!(intersection-1)$);
    \draw[-latex] (P4) -- ($(P4)!1cm!-90:(P1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I extend the line tangent to the end of the arc to the length of the perpendicular line?  I know I could make another perpendicular `\path` at the end of the first perpendicular line, then run a longer tangential `\path`, mark the intersection, and change my tangential line to that new marked intersection.  However, there has to be a better way.

Comment: @Jake I forgot to copy this over: `\draw[-latex] (P4) -- ($(P4)!1cm!-90:(P1)$);`  I will add it to the OP

Comment: Does the length of the perpendicular arrow have to be fixed, or would you also be happy with a solution where you fix the length of the tangential arrow and make the length of the perpendicular arrow depend on that?

Comment: @Jake either is fine.

Comment: This was exactly my question, too bad I don't understand the answer :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you name the coordinate at the end of the tangential arrow `(P5)`, you can use the `calc` library's projection syntax to draw the perpendicular arrow to the correct length.

Using the projection syntax, the expression

```
($(A)!(C)!(B)$)
```

describes the projection of `C` on the line from `A` to `B`. This can be combined with  the rotation syntax:

```
($(A)!(C)!90:(B)$)
```

describes the projection of `C` on the line from `A` to `B`, after that line has been rotated around `A` by 90 degrees.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap = round, line join = round, >=triangle 45]
    \coordinate (P1) at (-2, 0);
    \coordinate (P2) at (2.5, 0);
    \coordinate (P3) at (2, 0);

    \path[name path = line] (P1) -- (70: 4.5cm and 2.5cm);
    \path[name path = arc] (P3) arc (0:70: 4cm and 2cm) coordinate (P4);
    \path[name intersections = {of = line and arc, by = P4}];

    \begin{scope}
      \clip (P4) rectangle (P3);
      \draw (P3) arc (0:70: 4cm and 2cm);
    \end{scope}

    \draw[-latex] (P1) -- (P4);
    \path[name path = aux] (P4) circle [radius = 1bp];

    \draw[name intersections = {of = arc and aux}, -latex] (P4) --
    ($(intersection-2)!1.2cm!(intersection-1)$) coordinate (P5);
    \draw[-latex] (P4) -- ($(P4)!(P5)!-90:(P1)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an easier way then what I was going to do.